# How do I use a date function in Access?

Tags: date, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to put items into a table which have been deemed over due. I have the date of when items were completed last in a list, and I know the frequency of how often the items need to be completed.

> Ex. I have a cleaning that happened on 4/7/17 and it needs to be cleaned 30 days after it was last cleaned, and I have a cleaning that occurred 1/13/17 and it needs to be cleaned 90 days after it was last cleaned.

How can I get Access to show me overdue items in a separate list? If it helps, I will click a button before going to this table. The thing is, not every item needs to be cleaned at the same frequency. To my knowledge, Access doesn't have the date functions like Excel and you cannot type functions into a cell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 dim datedue as date, lastdate as date
 datedue = Dateadd("d", 30, lastdate)

 If datedue < Date() then
      'do stuff
 End if
```

This is basic syntax for checking dates. Since you didnt try anythin on your own, this is all you get.

Have fun   :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't "type functions into a cell", you set the *ControlSource* of a textbox. And Access has dozens of date functions.

However, you could start with a query:

```
Select 
    *,
    DateAdd("d", [CleaningFrequency], [LastCleaned]) As NextCleaning,
    IIf(DateDiff("d", [LastCleaned], Date()) > [CleaningFrequency], "Overdue", Null) As [Status],
    IIf(DateDiff("d", [LastCleaned], Date()) = [CleaningFrequency], "Yes", Null) As [Clean Today]
From
    YourTable
```

Of course, replace field and table names with those of yours.